# Can't find the dbus Settings Daemon - gmusicbrowser in Debian Jessie with Xfce

Tags: debian, d-bus

When I try to enable the `Gnome mmkeys` plugin in gmusicbrowser I get:

> **Error**: Can't find the dbus Settings Daemon for gnome or MATE

I already have installed `gnome-keyring` package, which seems to be the relevant component here. Any idea what is going on? I have a fresh install of Debian Jessie with Xfce.

[image]

Comment: `gnome-keyring` package has nothing to do with dbus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, that plug-in doesn't work with `xfce`. Still, the multimedia keys can be enabled using the method described [here](http://xubuntugeek.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/use-multimedia-keys-with-gmusicbrowser.html), as suggested by don_crissti. The two steps are:

1. Download script:

   ```
   sudo wget -q -O /tmp/gmb.sh https://goo.gl/18uaAO
   ```
2. Install:

   ```
   bash /tmp/gmb.sh install
   ```

That's it! Multimedia keys working flawlessly on Debian Jessie Xfce